# Select statement based on category

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table like this

```
Code 
A123
B3123
C93485
D345
E29845
```

The first letter of rows in code column are classified into the following:

```
Char Category
A-B      A
C        B
D-E      C
```

I would like to display the output table like this

```
Category Total Percentage
A          2     0.4%
B          1     0.2%   
C          2     0.4%
     Total 5     1.0%
```

I'm not sure how to start. Any hints or help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN SUBSTR(Code, 1, 1) IN ('A', 'B') THEN 'A'
         WHEN SUBSTR(Code, 1, 1) = 'C' THEN 'B'
         ELSE 'C' END AS Category,
    COUNT(*) AS Total,
    200.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS Percentage
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    ROLLUP(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(Code, 1, 1) IN ('A', 'B') THEN 'A'
         WHEN SUBSTR(Code, 1, 1) = 'C' THEN 'B'
         ELSE 'C' END);
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

This approach uses a `CASE` expression on the first letter of each code to assign a category.  Then, we aggregate by category and find the totals, as well as the percentages.  Note that `ROLLUP` is used to generate a total record at the bottom of the result set.  As a side effect of this, we multiply by 200%, because the summary row already contains the entire table count, which then gets counted twice.

Comment: hi. how can I replace null with "total"?

Comment: @llamaro25 Use `COALESCE` on the case expression for the category, and replace `NULL` with `total`.  [See the updated demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b103f4fb42b80e37ea60449561a9715c).